# Angular2 reactive forms show error messages based on validation fail condition

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I want to mention that i am using separate generic component, to display errors, so I am not putting them directly inside of html to avoid repetition, so I can't chain and hardcode conditional directly in template.

I have this field and two validations applied:

```
this.username = new FormControl('', [ Validators.minLength(5), Validators.required ]);
```

How do I show validation error message for each of validations? Let's say I want to show both errors if nothing is in field on submit:
**"Minimum length is 5"

"Field is required"**

And then if you put something inside it should only show:
**"Minimum length is 5"**

This is an example but, my real life example is comparing two email fields, if they are the same, so if email is not correct is should show:
**"Email is not correct"

"Email is not the same as first email field"**

So if email is correct and emails are not the same should only show:
**"Email is not the same as first email field"**

I have validations working if not passed, but I am not sure how to show separately if one validation passed and another one not, because I have to properly append the real reason why it failed and not put some generic reason for both.

Full example:

Component for error display:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-field-error-display',
  templateUrl: './field.error.display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field.error.display.component.css']
})
export class FieldErrorDisplayComponent
{
    @Input() errorMsg: string;
    @Input() displayError: boolean;
}
```

Component html:

```
<div *ngIf="displayError" >
  <small>{{errorMsg}}</small>
</div>
```

Usage of erorr display in Register.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="_form" (ngSubmit)="register()">
<h4>Create a new account</h4>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="email" formControlName="email" />
  <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldValid(_form,'email')" errorMsg="Please insert correct email"></app-field-error-display>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="emailConfirm">Email Address Confirm</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="emailConfirm" formControlName="emailConfirm" />
  <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldValid(_form,'emailConfirm')" errorMsg="Please insert correct email"></app-field-error-display>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="password" formControlName="password" />
  <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldValid(_form,'password')" errorMsg="Please insert password"></app-field-error-display>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create Account</button>
</form>
<div *ngIf="_registered" class="alert alert-success box-msg" role="alert">
  <strong>Account registered!</strong> You will be redirected in sec
</div>
```

Register component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._form = this._formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        emailConfirm: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, MatchOtherValidator.Validate('email')]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    this._registerModel = new RegisterModel();
}
```

Custom match other validator:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class MatchOtherValidator {
    static Validate(otherControlName: string) {

        let thisControl: FormControl;
        let otherControl: FormControl;

        return function matchOtherValidate(control: FormControl) {

            if (!control.parent) {
                return null;
            }

            // Initializing the validator.
            if (!thisControl) {
                thisControl = control;
                otherControl = control.parent.get(otherControlName) as FormControl;
                if (!otherControl) {
                    throw new Error('matchOtherValidator(): other control is not found in parent group');
                }
                otherControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
                    thisControl.updateValueAndValidity();
                });
            }

            if (!otherControl) {
                return null;
            }

            if (otherControl.value !== thisControl.value) {
                return {
                    matchOther: true
                };
            }

            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Form validation service has this method:

```
public IsFieldValid(form: FormGroup, field: string){
    return !form.get(field).valid && form.get(field).dirty;
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators: `*ngIf="username.errors.minlength"`, `*ngIf="username.errors.required"`.

Comment: can't chain in template directly.

Comment: You put the first condition on the element displaying your min length message, and the second one on the element dispplaying your required message. As shown in the documentation I linked to. What's the concrete problem? Where is your code?

Comment: I added code I hope it makes sense

Comment: It seems you haven't read my comment. Your code only checks if the form control is dirty and invalid. But you want to check if a specific validation fails: `return  form.get(field).dirty && form.get(field).errors.required` to check for the required validation, for example. You can't possibly know, from the `invalid` boolean, which can only be true or false, which of the validations failed.

Comment: I get it, but not all of fields ever will have required error, so I can't hardcode "errors.required" in generic method, is there a way i can dynamically pass the type of validation like for getting the field aka `form.get(field).errors.check(errorType)` while errorType is string or whatever, so i can pass "errorType" as parameter into method?

Comment: Pass the name of the validation error as an additional argument ('minlength', 'required', etc.), and use `form.get(field).errors[validationName]`, or simply `form.get(field).hasError(error)`. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasError

Comment: Brilliant, that's what i wanted, please put it in answer so i can mark it. thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your code only checks if the form control is dirty and invalid. But you want to check if a specific validation fails. So you need to pass an additional `error` argument ('required', 'minlength', etc.), and use

```
form.get(field).hasError(error)
```

Comment: one more thing though, if I have custom validator it is not showing, i tried with prebuild validators. As you can see in emailConfirm I have `MatchOtherValidator.Validate('email')]` and method is up, how do I check pass custom validator in hasError?

Comment: @AmelSalibasic  if custome validator matchOther fails you should return {matchOther: true} and check form.get(field).hasError('matchOther');

Answer (score 16):

I am answering this a little late, but I found a solution that is part of the angular materials modules that I really liked. If you implement your fields using "mat-form-field" you can easily display the error messages using a "mat-error" containing spans with an *ngIf.

I figured I should put it out there for other people trying to implement validator error messages. It makes the HTML a little beefy but it looks really nice.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="user_input">
            <mat-error>
                <span *ngIf="myForm?.controls.user_input?.errors?.required">Required Field</span>
                <span *ngIf="myForm?.controls.user_input?.errors?.minLength">Minimum Length is 5</span>
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

The documentation is found here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages

Comment: Note that `mat-form-field` and `mat-error` are not _built into angular_, they are part of a _separate_ Angular Material UI package. OP didn't mention he's using it.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov good catch. I'll change the wording there.

Answer (score 1):

if custome validator matchOther fails you should return {matchOther: true} and check `form.get(field).hasError('matchOther');`

Answer (score 1):

In the template you can use

```html
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formName" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">

<input matInput #inputName formControlName="inputName"
              name="inputName" required/>
  <mat-error *ngIf="formName.get('inputName').hasError('required')">
        Email is <strong>required</strong>
  </mat-error>
</form>
```